# How to set the swipe threshold to half the screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, threshold

I have a list (recycleView) of names.  Some names are short, some are long.  I want to delete them on swipe, but I want to make sure the user swipes more than half the distance of the **screen** (or width of list).

Currently it is going by the length of the individual item.

I know how to swipe on delete.  I have tried overrideing getSwipeThreshold but again that uses the size of the item as its base.

Here's code because SO wants code:

```
     RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.edit_list);
     final MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new 
     MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, qnames);

    //set swipe behavior
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;  //do not allow move
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            // Row is swiped from recycler view
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(); //get position which is swipe
            qnames.remove(position);  //remove from display list
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());  //update the view

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            // view the background view

            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }

        @Override
        public float getSwipeThreshold( RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){

            return .9f;
        }
```

Here's some pictures.

[image: is delete]
[image: not deleted]

So how do I set the swipe threshold to half the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return 0.5f in getSwipeThreshold. This is default value, so just remove this override from your class&

Comment: Please explain your answer more clearly with correct punctuations.

Comment: The "get Swipe Threshold ()" method returns 0.5f by default, this can be seen in the super class. That's what you need. 0.5f means that the action will be considered completed if the card shifts half the width of the screen.
1f - means that the action will be performed with a full card swap.
0.1f - the action will be performed when the card moves to 10% of the screen width